# jQuery hover function if/then is really slow to fire

Tags: jquery

The following function works for me but it is very slow to react to the hover. Basically I have a nav that is in the middle of the page that has a "drop up", then when the user scrolls to the top of the page, the nav becomes sticky and "drops down". But like I said, it's very slow to react to the hover and I'm not sure why.

Here is a jsfiddle > http://jsfiddle.net/acrane/dgvj7Ls7/

and the function:

```
$('.main-navigation li a').hover(function() {

if ( $('.main-navigation').hasClass('main-nav-pos') ) {

$('.main-nav-pos li a').hover(
function() {
//display heading and caption
$(this).children('.nav-info').animate({"height":"100%"}, 100);
$(this).children('.nav-info').animate({"top":"-105%"}, 'fast');
$(this).children('.butterfly').css({"display":"block"}, 'slow');
},

function() {
//hide heading and caption
$(this).children('.nav-info').animate({"height":"0"}, 100);
$(this).children('.nav-info').animate({"top":"0%"}, 'fast');
$(this).children('.butterfly').css({"display":"none"}, 'slow');
}
);

} else {

$('.main-nav-fixed li a').hover(
function() {
    //display heading and caption
    $(this).children('.nav-info-fixed').animate({"height":"100%"}, 100);
    $(this).children('.nav-info-fixed').animate({"top":"105%"}, 'fast');
    },
function() {
    //hide heading and caption
    $(this).children('.nav-info-fixed').animate({"height":"0"}, 100);
    $(this).children('.nav-info-fixed').animate({"top":"0%"}, 'fast');
    }
    );
}
})
```

Comment: It may be from the nested hovers you're doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding more and more `.hover()` handlers during first `$('.main-navigation li a').hover()`, which results in all kind of weird behaviour and perfomance.

Try to rewrite code in something like this:

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/dgvj7Ls7/8/).

```
$('.main-navigation li a').hover(
    function() {
        if ( $('.main-navigation').hasClass('main-nav-pos') ) {
            //display heading and caption
            $(this).children('.nav-info').animate({"height":"100%"}, 100);
            $(this).children('.nav-info').animate({"top":"-105%"}, 'fast');
            $(this).children('.butterfly').css({"display":"block"}, 'slow');
        }
        else
        {
            //display heading and caption
            $(this).children('.nav-info-fixed').animate({"height":"100%"}, 100);
            $(this).children('.nav-info-fixed').animate({"top":"105%"}, 'fast');
        }
    },
    function() {
        if ( $('.main-navigation').hasClass('main-nav-pos') ) {
            //hide heading and caption
            $(this).children('.nav-info').animate({"height":"0"}, 100);
            $(this).children('.nav-info').animate({"top":"0%"}, 'fast');
            $(this).children('.butterfly').css({"display":"none"}, 'slow');
        }
        else 
        {
            //hide heading and caption
            $(this).children('.nav-info-fixed').animate({"height":"0"}, 100);
            $(this).children('.nav-info-fixed').animate({"top":"0%"}, 'fast');
        }
    }
);
```